# Bad routing table?

Tags: linux, wifi

I've got a linux machine with a hotspot (interface wlp1s0) and a WiFi connection (interface wlxe84e063ea32c) setup to that hotspot. I know it's crazy, users can set this up themselves. I know the solution is to not set up things like this. I'm still surprised that it does not work. Why does it not work how should the routing table look like? The symptom is that a flask server cannot serve http pages from this machine, while I *can* ssh to it. Perhaps sshd & flask binds to port in different ways?

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     601    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
```

Interestingly plopping in an ethernet cable solves the problem. The routing table then looks like this

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     601    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

I'm connecting from my machine called "Silvia", lets call the problematic machine "foobar". The following connection scenario is the one not working when the WiFi is connected to the hotspot.

silvia -> hotspot -> foobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, you have two problems:

- without an ethernet cable, your default route is over your hotspot interface, because you have no other default route set - you should be able to reach your node from other hosts in the same broadcast domain (i.e. from other hosts in the 10.42.0.0/24 network), but you would not be able to reach it from anything else
- with an ethernet cable, you have a valid default route/gateway that does, in fact, work, in the sense that your host can now reach other nodes outside of the 10.42.0.0/24 network.

Basically, without the ethernet cable, this is working as best it can, which is not very well - without a default route, you can reach 10.42.0.0/24, but nothing else.

So yes, it doesn't make a ton of sense to have your host be a hotspot and a wireless client to its own hotspot, and without somewhere for the traffic to go, your hotspot will not be of that much use.

Updated to respond to comment below:

It might help to quickly parse out the routing table for the situation where you are connected to your own hotspot:

The line below says that traffic not matching any other route below should use 10.42.0.1 as a gateway.

```
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
```

The entry below says that to get to 10.42.0.0/24, wlp1s0 is the preferred device

```
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

The entry below says that to get to 10.42.0.0/24, wlxe84e063ea32c is the backup device

```
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     601    0        0 wlxe84e063ea32c
```

This entry is irrelevant for the discussion

```
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
```

Or, in simpler terms: wlp1s0 has no default gateway, but wlxe84e063ea32c is told that 10.42.0.1 is the default gateway. Since wlp1s0 is assigned 10.42.0.1, this means there is still, in effect, nowhere to non-local traffic to go.

Or, if I could draw, there would be a picture of `client NIC -> hostpot NIC -> hostpot NIC (because hotspot NIC is the default gateway)`

When you plug in the ethernet cable, wlp1s0 does have a default route, which is to send traffic over the wired NIC.

If I could draw, there would be a picture of `client NIC -> hotspot NIC -> wired interface -> internetz`

The issue is how, physically speaking, you are expecting 'physical' signals to travel between your hotspot, and the `foobar` node.

Either those signals travel as electrical pulses on a wire (which we know works), or both your hotspot and `foobar` communicate through radio signals, which would require `foobar` to connect to the hotspot.

Comment: no, I know it does not make any sense. :-) The question is why can't I connect to services via 10.42.0.0/24 when the WiFi device is connected to the hotspot, while if the the WiFi device is not connected to the hotspot I can?

Comment: Thanks for the editit, that makes lots of sense. Is there any way to re-arranging the routing table for this situation? It seems it should work if all traffic were routed through the hotspot only.... I feel packages are looped around and around somehow.

Comment: I can't see any way of making this work without the wired interface being active, or making your client NIC connect to some other hotspot.

Comment: but.... that's nuts, isn't it? Adding one more interface should not make the already working interface stop working?

Comment: Updated the Q slightly

Comment: Well, no, not really: if I have _one_ network interface, and that network interface is not connected to anything other than a local network, then that interface can only reach other hosts in the local network. And this is your situation. Whether or not you connect a client NIC to your hotspot doesn't make any difference to this, except it makes it seem like there is a default route. But that's because of your DHCP config, it doesn't reflect the reality that there is nowhere for non-local traffic to be sent.

Comment: But I'm only interested in local traffic...

Comment: Right - but physically, how do your 1s and 0s get from hotspot to foobar? If we refer to the OSI model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), then local traffic would be occuring at layer 2, which is built on a 'physical' layer 1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_1:_Physical_Layer). I don't see, in your setup, what provides layer 1 between hotspot and foobar

Comment: Foobar has two WiFi devices, one configured as a hotspot. The machine can naturally access it's own device, just like eth0. Sofar so god, however connecting the other WiFi device to the hotspot causes the issues.

Comment: I am getting a bit confused - could you update your question with some IPs and examples?